# Give error on overriding functions by mistake

Tags: typescript

When I inherit a class I don't want to override a base class method by mistake e.g.

```
class SomeComponent {
  show() {
    // ...
  }
}
class SpecializedComponent extends SomeComponent {
  show() { // Error here as its overriding
    // ...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to catch unexpected overrides and force some of annotation for intentional overrides?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with TypeScript 4.3 there is a new `--noImplicitOverride` compiler option that you can set to give an error of unintended overrides.

```
class SomeComponent {
  show() {
    // ...
  }
}
class SpecializedComponent extends SomeComponent {
  show() { // Error ❌ !
    // ...
  }
}
```

If you want to override *intentionally* you can use the `override` keyword:

```
class SomeComponent {
  show() {
    // ...
  }
}
class SpecializedComponent extends SomeComponent {
  override show() { // All good 
    // ...
  }
}
```

## More

This a very long standing and popular request : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arjrOdT73b4 ❤️